# XMLHTTPRequest / CORS?, Server always receive "Origin: null" on headers

Tags: javascript, html, server, cors, xmlhttprequest

I have a little server done with a MCU + ESP-01 WIFI module. On the PC, I created an HTML file with a button, when it is pressed it sends a GET request to the server board via internet. This is working and the response given by the board to the browser is being shown on the text-box of the HTML.
The response of the board includes on its header: "**HTTP/1.1 200 OK**", "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ***", "**Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST**", "**Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Origin**" and "**Content-Type: application/json**". Then after the headers goes a little JSON string as data (this JSON string is what is being shown on the text-box of the HTML).

Below is my code for the HTML button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>BUTTON OVER INTERNET</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>

    <body>

        <input type="text" id="result_text" size="15">
        <input type="button" onclick="Send()" value="SEND-REQUEST">

        <script>

            function Send() 
            {
                document.getElementById("result_text").value = "";

                var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

                XHR.open("GET", "http://163.192.145.78:8383/internet_test", true);
                XHR.setRequestHeader("Origin", "http://someIP.com");
                XHR.timeout = 4000;

                XHR.onreadystatechange = function() 
                {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                    {
                        document.getElementById("result_text").value = this.responseText;
                        XHR.abort();
                    }
                };

                XHR.ontimeout = function (e) 
                {
                    alert("TIMEOUT!");
                    XHR.abort();
                };

                XHR.send();
            }

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Below is the packet that the MCU is receving for each request:

[image: Packet received by the server]

The "Origin" field on the header received by the MCU (server) have always "null" value. And in my application with that server I want to identify from where the request is coming for security purposes. What is missing?

Also, I have tried to add to the XMLHTTPRequest after XHR.open, something like this:
**XHR.setRequestHeader("Origin", "http://www.someIP.com");**
But the Origin is also null doing this way...

For now, the application will use this HTML button from a local file (In a way that I can send the HTML to another person via WhatsApp for example), not in a server. In this case, it is possible to attach the Origin to it?

Well, I need to identify from where the request is coming...

Answer (score 1):

The Origin is always where the HTML document was loaded from. If that's the user's filesystem then it will always be `null`. There is nothing you can do about that.

If you want to know where the request is coming from, then look at the IP address the request is coming from.

Comment: For example, I can make my button do a request for a server like whatismyip.com to obtain the sender IP, and attach the IP value to the data field, so this way the server will be able to know what is the origin... Do you mean something like this? What other ideas you have? Because you said "If you want to know where the request is coming from, then look at the IP address the request is coming from."

Comment: You can get the IP address from the request without involving a third party (how you do that depends on your server-side environment).

Comment: The server is only a simple board connected to a router/modem, we are currently using port forwarding from an external port to an internal port 80 to the internal ip given to this board. Do you know if there is something I can configure on the router to identify from where the request is coming?